# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.storage' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I developed a flask app on localhost and now I want to publish it by google cloud platform. Problem occurs when trying to read/write a file in google cloud storage.

First I installed google-cloud-storage via pip:

*pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage*

then my code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
data_file_path = "url-to-txt-file-in-google-storage"
with storage.open(data_file_path, "wb") as gcsFile:
    gcsFile.write("xx")
```

At this point error says: **AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.storage' has no attribute 'open'**

I also tried it with *pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient* but it didn't work either.

What should I do to make it work? How could I read and write to a file in google cloud storage without downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error is very clear, `google.cloud.storage` is a python package, it is not an object so it doesn't have `open()` method or any method. Actually you can see the source code here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/main/google/cloud/storage

Basically you need to create a `Client` first. If you want to just copy the file, here is an example:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#storage-copy-object-python

```
from google.cloud import storage


def copy_blob(
    bucket_name, blob_name, destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name
):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # blob_name = "your-object-name"
    # destination_bucket_name = "destination-bucket-name"
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```

Comment: Could I read and write to a file in google cloud storage without downloading it by creating Client?